# How do you distinguish between socket.io calls when their messages are the same?

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

Let's say I have a socket server that is listening on a generic `message`, and only alters its  behaviour due to different payloads. For example:

```
socket.on('users.get', function(payload) {
    // retrieve user data
    // return data that corresponds to the data requested in "payload"

    socket.emit('users.get', returnData);
});
```

If two socket `emit`s are made with the `users.get` message, how would I be able to distinguish between their returns on the client side, assuming both are made in the same page?

The immediate solution would be to merge the two calls together, but if that situation were impossible, how would I manage it otherwise? In this particular instance, one `users.get` call is made in the header of the page on page load, and another `users.get` is made from inside the page content.

Knowing full well that one call is in the header, and another is in the content means that it *might* work if on the client-side, `.once()` is used instead of `.on()`, but that still involves a race condition, so I was wondering if there were any standard way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 1):

A given instance of `socket` (the thing you call `.on` on) equals a connection, which in turn equals a specific client. If 2 clients make a similar `emit` it will arrive on 2 different sockets, and your handler can you the `socket` instance to return the response to the specific client.

If the same socket makes 2 emits, then that's a client-server app-level protocol issue, and should be handled in the client and in the server. Maybe it means there's no really no difference (to your app) between the requests, so it doesn't matter which responses arrives 'first'. If there *is* a difference, then maybe add a "request id" field to the request, and echo that field in the response, allowing the client to associate each response with the original request that triggered it.

Comment: There is no specific method to distinguish between same requests from the same user?